# Is there a way for a C# subscribing object to unsubscribe an event, without directly knowing the object it is subscribed to?

Tags: c#, events, memory-leaks

I have a user control that subscribes a list of `inner` objects to objects in another component. There are times I want to remove the `inner` objects based on a property settings change of the user control. If I blindly remove them from the list without unsubscribing, I think this will cause a memory leak of the orphaned `inner` objects.

There are times that I may not have access to the list of objects that I had when we subscribed. For example the list of items I am subscribed to may have been changed and this is one of the reasons I am unsubscribing.

I certainly can add a reference to the subscribed object in my code to each of these inner objects, but I’m interested seeing if there is a built-in mechanism that I can leverage.

**Update #1:**
Hans requested some code. I made up a sample that I think shows that the `innerObject` are not released when the list is cleared. I think this is equivalent to setting their reference to null.

```
/*
 * Program that demonstrates that event subscribers stay alive after
 * loosing scope.
 * 
 * The question is asking if I don't have a reference to myObject is there a way to 
 * unsubscribe with what the innerObject knows natively.
 * 
 * In the Unsubscribe() method I have examples of unsubscribing using a "known" myObject
 * and one with a self reference to the myObject.
 * 
 * The solution that uses IObserver and IObservable automates a way to store an explicit
 * reference to the subscription holder.
 * 
 */

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Sample objects that subscribe to MyObject's Updated event
  /// </summary>
  public class InnerObject
  {
    public MyObject Subscribed { get; set; }
    public void Updated(object sender, MyObjectUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Object that publishes the Updated event
  /// </summary>
  public class MyObject
  {
    private string data_;

    public event EventHandler<MyObjectUpdateEventArgs> Updated;

    public string Data { get { return data_; } set { SetMyData(value); } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Outputs the Data string
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
      return Data;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event handler
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void OnUpdate(MyObjectUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
      EventHandler<MyObjectUpdateEventArgs> handler = Updated;
      if (Updated != null) {
        handler(this, e);
      }
    }

    private void SetMyData(string value)
    {
      if (Data != value) {
        data_ = value;
        OnUpdate(new MyObjectUpdateEventArgs(Data));
      }
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// EventArgs to provide updated MyData value;
  /// </summary>
  public class MyObjectUpdateEventArgs
  {
    public MyObjectUpdateEventArgs(string data)
    {
      Data = data;
    }

    public string Data { get; set; }
  }

  internal class Program
  {
    private static List<InnerObject> innerObjectsList = new List<InnerObject>();

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
      myObject.Data = "Hello World";
      Console.WriteLine(myObject.ToString());
      Console.ReadLine();

      // Create the innerObjectts and subscribe
      MakeNewInnerObjects(5, myObject);

      // This will cause all of the inner objects to respond with myObjects Data string
      Console.WriteLine("Assigning new data to myObject\n");
      myObject.Data = "Hello InnerObjects";

      // Shows they are responding, even though the list and the items are out of scope
      Console.ReadLine();

      // Uncomment to unsubscribe
      // Unsubscribe(myObject);
      innerObjectsList.Clear();

      // Force garbage collection for our example
      GC.Collect();
      GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

      Console.WriteLine("Assigning new data to myObject\n");
      myObject.Data = "Are you still there InnerObjects?";

      // Shows they still exist if we don't unsubscribe
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a count of InnerObjects, subscribe them to myObject and add to the list
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="count"></param>
    private static void MakeNewInnerObjects(int count, MyObject myObject)
    {
      // Uncomment if you want to have the list go out of scope as well to show
      // That the reference keeps them alive
      //List<InnerObject> innerObjectsList = new List<InnerObject>();

      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        InnerObject innerObject = new InnerObject();
        innerObject.Subscribed = myObject;
        myObject.Updated += innerObject.Updated;
        innerObjectsList.Add(innerObject);
      }
    }

    // Unsubscribe the list of innerObJects from MyObject
    private static void Unsubscribe(MyObject myObject)
    {
      // Two ways to unsubscribe, the first depends on knowing what we subscribbed to
      // the second uses a stored reference to the object
      foreach (InnerObject innerObject in innerObjectsList) {
        // myObject.Updated -= innerObject.Updated;
        innerObject.Subscribed.Updated -= innerObject.Updated;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Pretty vague without a snippet, but there is no obvious danger of a "leak", these "inner objects" keep a reference to your UC through the event subscription.  In other words, those objects keep your UC alive, not the other way around.  If your UC keeps a reference to such an inner object then all you have to do is set it to null.

Comment: If the inner objects are removed from the control's list, the only reference to them would be through the MyObject event that they subscribed to. Wouldn't that keep the inner object alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement `IObservable` for your publishers then the `Subscribe` call will return a subscription object that will unsubscribe when you destroy it.  Something like this:

```
public class Observable<T> : IObservable<T>
{
    protected readonly List<IObserver<T>> _subscribers = new List<IObserver<T>>();

    private class Subscription : IDisposable
    {
        List<IObserver<T>> _subscribers;
        IObserver<T> _observer;
        public Subscription(List<IObserver<T>> subscribers, IObserver<T> observer)
        {
            _subscribers = subscribers;
            _observer = observer;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _subscribers.Remove(_observer);
        }
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        _subscribers.Add(observer);
        return new Subscription(_subscribers, observer);
    }
}
```

The `Subscription` class does all the work of disconnecting.  The other side of the puzzle is the subscriber:

```
public abstract class Observer<T> : IObserver<T>, IDisposable
{
    private IDisposable _subscription = null;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Unsubscribe();
    }

    public void Unsubscribe()
    {
        if (_subscription != null)
        {
            _subscription.Dispose();
            _subscription = null;
        }
    }

    public void SubscribeTo(IObservable<T> publisher)
    {
        Unsubscribe();
        _subscription = publisher.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public virtual void OnCompleted()
    { }

    public abstract void OnError(Exception error)
    { }

    public abstract void OnNext(T value);
}
```

Even if you're not using `IObservable<T>` and `IObserver<T>` the basic principle is the same.  You track the subscribers at the publisher/`IObservable` and hand out subscriptions that can remove the subscriber from the publisher's list.  The subscribers then only have to track their subscriptions.

---

Update: here's a usage example for the above classes.

First, a handy function to add to the `Observable<T>` class:

```
public virtual void Publish(T value)
{
    foreach (var sub in _subscribers.Distinct().ToArray())
    {
        try
        {
            sub.OnNext(value);
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

That gives a simple method for notifying all of the subscribers that there is something happening.  Now, a slightly contrived example:

```
public class KeyPublisher : Observable<ConsoleKeyInfo>
{
}

public class PrintKeys : Observer<ConsoleKeyInfo>
{
    public override void OnNext(ConsoleKeyInfo next)
    {
        if (next.Modifiers != 0)
            Console.Write("{0}-", next.Modifiers.ToString().Replace(", ", "-"));
        Console.WriteLine(next.Key);
    }
}

public class DetectEscape : Observer<ConsoleKeyInfo>
{
    public bool FoundEscape { get; private set; }

    public override void OnNext(ConsoleKeyInfo next)
    {
        if (next.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            FoundEscape = true;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pub = new KeyPublisher();

        using (var sub1 = new PrintKeys())
        using (var sub2 = new DetectEscape())
        {
            sub1.SubscribeTo(pub);
            sub2.SubscribeTo(pub);

            while (!sub2.FoundEscape)
            {
                pub.Publish(Console.ReadKey(true));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you have a problem with object lifespan due to references being held by the various lists and subscriptions, the solution might be to use `WeakReference`s.  Here's a version of the `Subscription` class that uses weak references:

```
private class Subscription : IDisposable
{
    WeakReference<List<IObserver<T>>> _subscribers;
    WeakReference<IObserver<T>> _observer;

    public Subscription(List<IObserver<T>> subscribers, IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        _subscribers = new WeakReference<List<IObserver<T>>>(subscribers);
        _observer = new WeakReference<IObserver<T>>(observer);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_subscribers != null && _observer != null)
        {
            List<IObserver<T>> subscribers;
            IObserver<T> observer;
            if (_subscribers.TryGetTarget(out subscribers) && _observer.TryGetTarget(out observer))
                subscribers.Remove(observer);
            _subscribers = null;
            _observer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

You can do the same with the `_subscribers` list (have it hold `WeakReference<IObserver<T>>`) to stop it from holding subscribers back from garbage collection... but I think that it is much better practice to manage the lifecycle of your `IDisposable` objects.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if there were a usage example provided. As it stands, it is not clear how to wire this up.

Comment: I'm looking into the pattern. Not sure of the benefit yet.